# Python 3 - Counting up with two different values

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I am trying to figure out how to count up to a certain integer (as a range) alternating between two different numbers like 2 and 3. So that the output would be 2 5 7 10 12 15 etc.

I started off trying to alter a simple while loop like the following to take two values:

```
a = 0 
while a < 100: 
    a = a + 2 + 3
    print(a, end=' ')
```

But it just ends up counting up to 100 by 5.

I have tried number ranges and for loops and modules like itertools to try and figure out a way to do this and I am completely stumped.

I have performed search after search on this and all I can find is counting up by a single number with loops and ranges.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. I really appreciate all the help from all of you. Stack Overflow is great. It is amazing what I still have to learn. And thank you PM 2Ring for letting me know how to show that my problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `itertools.cycle` for this

```
import itertools
a = 0
it = itertools.cycle((2,3))
while a < 100:
    a += next(it)
    print(a)
```

Output

```
2
5
7
10
...
95
97
100
```

The `itertools.cycle` generator will just continuously loop back over the tuple as many times as you call it.

Comment: Another aproach using cycle - iterate it directly and check if `a < 100` inside that loop

Comment: Fair enough. I wonder if the OP will understand my answer. ;)

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. I really appreciate all the help from all of you. Stack Overflow is great. It is amazing what I still have to learn.

Answer (score 6):

You need to print the content of `a` after adding two, and after adding three:

```
a = 0
while a < 100: 
    a = a + 2
    print(a, end=' ')
    if a < 100:
        a = a + 3
        print(a, end=' ')
```

That being said, you can better construct a generator, that iteratively adds two and three interleaved:

```
def add_two_three(a):
    while True:
        a += 2
        yield a
        a += 3
        yield a
```

You can then print the content of the generator until it hits 100 or more:

```
from itertools import takewhile

print(' '.join(takewhile(lambda x: x < 100,add_two_three(0))))
```

Comment: Using a generator is the sensible way, but it may be a bit too advanced for the OP.

Comment: Your first solution needs a check before the second addition, or it might count beyond the bounds.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. I really appreciate all the help from all of you. Stack Overflow is great. It is amazing what I still have to learn.

Answer (score 2):

You have to increment `a` with different value each time (2 and 3). You can just swap the two values being used to increment `a` on each iteration to achieve this.

```
a = 0
inc1 = 2   # values being used to increment a
inc2 = 3
while a < 100:
    a = a + inc1
    inc1, inc2 = inc2, inc1    # swap the values
    print(a, end=' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun...

```
# Count from zero to 100, alternating between i and j
i, j = 2, 3
k = i + j

a = 0 
while a < 100: 
    a += a % k and j or i
    print(a, end=' ')
print()
```

**output**

```
2 5 7 10 12 15 17 20 22 25 27 30 32 35 37 40 42 45 47 50 52 55 57 60 62 65 67 70 72 75 77 80 82 85 87 90 92 95 97 100
```

Comment: Why the extra print statement?

Comment: @toonarmycaptain Because I want a newline at the end of the output. Otherwise, my terminal prompt won't start at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Oh ok. All of mine did.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. I really appreciate all the help from all of you. Stack Overflow is great. It is amazing what I still have to learn.

Comment: No worries, @BruceL .

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

np.cumsum([2,3] * 20)
```

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. I really appreciate all the help from all of you. Stack Overflow is great. It is amazing what I still have to learn.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this should do it:

```
a = 0 
while a < 100: 
    a = a + 2
    print(a, end=' ')
    a = a + 3
    print(a, end=' ')
```

Instead of printing, you could add those values to a list for later use.

Answer (score 0):

```
def createRange(a,end,step1,step2):
    output=[]
    while a < end: 
        a += step1
        output.append(a)
        if a < end:
            a += step2
            output.append(a)
    return output

array = createRange(2,100,2,3)
print array
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if` statement like this:

```
a = 0
i = 0
while a < 100:
    if i % 2:
        a = a + 3
    else:
        a = a + 2
    i += 1
    print(a, end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do more or less what you're doing, just split the additions of 2 and 3:

```
a = 0 
while a < 100: 
    a = a + 2
    print(a, end=' ')
    if a > 97:  # you don't actually need this because of how the numbers 2/3 work
        break   # but this will check if a will be >100 after addition of the second number
    a = a +3
    print(a, end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

This short expression works:

```
for a in (x // 10 for x in range(0,1000,25)):
    print(a)
```

(but I cannot recommend it)